# Digital filters that can be applied to both static and dynamic measurements

Tags: sensor, filter, noise, digital-filter

Is there a digital filter that can be applied to both static and dynamic measurements WITHOUT changing the parameters of the digital filter?

For example I made a temperature measuring device that can be used to measure both static and dynamic temperatures. I have the following case

1. I measure the temperature with a fixed/static temperature, but the measured data has noise (the value is volatile)
2. I measured the temperature of the heated water (dynamic) and the measured data also contained noise.

I want case 1 and case 2 to use one digital filter with the same filter parameters. Is there a digital filter that can do that?

Comment: Not clear what is case 1. Can you give an example, say room temperature which does not vary much with time (seconds), so can be seen as "static", but there is still noise, say mains 50/60Hz, which can be filtered by high/band pass filter. In case 2, boiling water is "dynamic", comparing with case 1. Of course you can use a two in one filter, the but the traded off "free size like" parameters might not suit both worlds.

Comment: Noise in case 1 is like there is a problem with the sensor and I want to use a digital filter instead of an analog filter

Comment: A simple 1 tap IIR lowpass filter will probably do what you want at minimum effort. Set the cutoff frequency high enough to allow for a reasonable response time for your dynamic heater temperature. Going forward you can implement a notch filter to stop small bandwidth interference if present (e.g. mains harmonics)

Comment: There's no such thing as a universal filter. Any filter will have to be calculated for the needed requirements. If those happen to coincide in your two cases then sure, you can have the same filter for both. But why a digital, in particular? Why not analog? You seem to be insisting on it.

Comment: Yes I agree that the source of noise be best handled at the source with filters and or pre-amplifiers etc depending on your acceptable noise levels. You'd better work out if the same noise in case 1 that you see in the digital domain is also observable in the analogue domain and if possible the spectrum of this noise, then you could look at doing filtering both in the analogue and digital domain as required to meet both 1 & 2 of your goals